# Vue composition api persisting state on refresh

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, vuex, vue-composition-api

I have a basic composition function which pulls in data from an api.

This is fine there are lots of good examples

https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/state-management-with-composition-api/

I can share state between pages but refreshing any page resets my data. Is there a standard or good practice way to handle this? I use vuexpersist with vuex to solve this.

Are people just writing manually to localstorage?

Answer (score -1):

If you refresh or reload, the "state" is expected to be missing since you are loading the app again. If you need data persistency then manually writing to local storage is the common action (so that is a yes for your last question).

You need to manually write the state recovery for your app, could it be by restoring data from local storage, retrieving data again from the API or even restoring the user session if you need authentication.